# How to make tomcat FIPS Mode enabling

Tags: tomcat, openssl, tomcat7, fips

i have added this in server.xml to enable tomcat FIPSMode

```
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"
 SSLEngine="on" FIPSMode="on" />
```

But after that logs are throwing,

```
Dec 01, 2015 3:28:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
SEVERE: Failed to enter FIPS mode
java.lang.Error: Failed to enter FIPS mode
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(AprLifecycleListener.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
```

when i check the [tomcat 7 docs for FIPSMode](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html#APR_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener)

it is asking us to create OpenSSL library

```
FIPS mode requires you to have a FIPS-capable OpenSSL library which you must build yourself. If this attribute is set to any of the above values, the SSLEngine must be enabled as well.
```

So, now the question is how to create OpenSSL library for tomcat FIPS ? and how to integrate it with tomcat ?

please share the steps or documentation to achieve this

Please check this new exception #1

```
Dec 03, 2015 1:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.2.
Dec 03, 2015 1:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Dec 03, 2015 1:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: Initializing FIPS mode...
Dec 03, 2015 1:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
SEVERE: Failed to initialize the SSLEngine.
java.lang.Exception: error:2D06C06E:FIPS routines:FIPS_mode_set:fingerprint does not match
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.fipsModeSet(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL(AprLifecycleListener.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(AprLifecycleListener.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

Dec 03, 2015 1:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
SEVERE: Failed to enter FIPS mode
java.lang.Error: Failed to enter FIPS mode
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(AprLifecycleListener.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

java.lang.Error: Failed to enter FIPS mode
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(AprLifecycleListener.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
```

openssl version

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
```

**Please check the new exception#2**

```
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.577 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.29
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.578 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 20 2015 09:18:00 UTC
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.578 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.29.0
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_80-b15
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.29
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.587 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.29
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.587 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.29/conf/logging.properties
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.588 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.588 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.29/endorsed
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.589 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.29
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.590 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.29
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.590 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.29/temp
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.590 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.2.
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.591 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.657 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL Initializing FIPS mode...
03-Dec-2015 22:46:24.691 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Failed to initialize the SSLEngine.
 java.lang.Exception: error:2D06C06E:FIPS routines:FIPS_mode_set:fingerprint does not match
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.fipsModeSet(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL(AprLifecycleListener.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(AprLifecycleListener.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
```

**Finaly Worked!!**

```
04-Dec-2015 00:45:30.500 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.2.
04-Dec-2015 00:45:30.500 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
04-Dec-2015 00:45:30.561 INFO [main] **org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL Initializing FIPS mode...
04-Dec-2015 00:45:30.576 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL Successfully entered FIPS mode**
04-Dec-2015 00:45:30.577 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015)
04-Dec-2015 00:45:30.935 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
04-Dec-2015 00:45:30.973 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
04-Dec-2015 00:45:30.976 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2308 ms
```

Comment: Have you also set your JVM to FIPS mode?

Comment: No...is that necessary ?

Comment: Actually we still doing test on this tomcat. i heard there is another method through Java. but for me it worked for Linux and Solaris.

Comment: AFAIK, `FIPSMode="on"` only applies to the OpenSSL library in the APR listener. The rest of the JVM won't be running in FIPS mode. You need to follow http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/FIPS.html for FIPS mode

Comment: Oh Yes...i'm sorry. i forgot to check. actually our jre is already FIPS enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Tomcat to work with APR connectors, here the steps (did it on CentOS 6):

**Install gcc**

```
yum install gcc
```

**Install latest APR**

```
wget http://apache.spd.co.il//apr/apr-1.5.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf apr-1.5.1.tar.gz
cd apr-1.5.1/
./configure
make
make install
```

**Install latest APR-util**

```
wget http://apache.spd.co.il/apr/apr-util-1.5.3.tar.gz
tar -zxvf apr-util-1.5.3.tar.gz
cd apr-util-1.5.3
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr
make
make install
```

**Configure OpenSSL**

Check installed version by executing:

```
openssl version
```

Example output: **OpenSSL 1.0.1h-fips 5 Jun 2014**

Note the installed version compiled in FIPS mode, google for manuals to do so.
Copy the corresponding source version files from OpenSSL site to your machine /var/tmp/openssl-1.0.1h

**JDK**

In order to build tomcat's JNI wrapper, ensure that JDK is available (copy it to the machine, note that the JDK version must be the same as installed JRE).

**Install JNI Wrapper for APR used by Tomcat (libtcnative)**

```
cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
tar -zxvf tomcat-native.tar.gz
cd tomcat-native/jni/native
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-java-home=$JDK_HOME --prefix=/usr --with-ssl=/var/tmp/openssl-1.0.1h/build/lnx/devel/x86_64
make
make install
```

**Configure your CA**

Edit the copied openssl.cnf file with setting the dir property under the CA_default section.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Configuring your CA
mkdir -p /var/tmp/myCA/certs
mkdir /var/tmp/myCA/csr
mkdir /var/tmp/myCA/newcerts
mkdir /var/tmp/myCA/private
cp /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf /var/tmp/myCA/.
cd /var/tmp/myCA
echo 00 > serial
echo 00 > crlnumber
touch index.txt

# Create CA private key
openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout pass:qwerty -out  private/rootCA.key 2048

# Remove passphrase
openssl rsa -passin pass:qwerty -in private/rootCA.key -out private/rootCA.key

# Create CA self-signed certificate
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -x509 -subj '/C=IL/L=Tel-Aviv/CN=www.imperva.com' -days 365 -key private/rootCA.key -out certs/rootCA.crt

# Create a SSL Server certificate
# Create private key for the mx server
openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout pass:qwerty -out private/mx.key 2048

# Remove passphrase
openssl rsa -passin pass:qwerty -in private/mx.key -out private/mx.key

# Create CSR (Certificate Signing Request) for the MX server
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -subj '/C=IL/L=Tel-Aviv/CN=mx' -key private/mx.key -out csr/mx.csr

# Create certificate for the MX server
openssl ca -batch -config openssl.cnf -days 365 -in csr/mx.csr -out certs/mx.crt -keyfile private/rootCA.key -cert certs/rootCA.crt -policy policy_anything
```

**Configure Tomcat**

Edit server.xml to use Http11AprProtocol protocol:

```
<Connector
        interface="management"
        port="8080"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
        secure="false"
        SSLEnabled="false"
        scheme="http"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8"
        minProcessors="5"
        maxProcessors="150"
        enableLookups="true"
        acceptCount="10"
        allowChunking="true"
        server="NA"/>
```

Comment: but i get these exception, please check the updated question

Comment: That looks like APR is loaded and seems like no issue that. but why this FIPS is not able to enable ?

Comment: The error happens due to wrong versions compatibility between the run time openssl version to your compiled version.

Comment: openssl  version is giving OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
 and this is what i downloaded from openssl page

Comment: Hi Maxim, could you please check the updated exception. and how i make run time openssl == compiled version ? the "openssl version" is returning the new version only

Comment: Finally worked, mistake was while installing TC-native.     made like this and worked                     ./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=$JAVA_HOME --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/ --prefix=$CATALINA_HOME